# Regex for markdown # title but don't allow space before closing #

Tags: regex

I am working to write a `regex` for Markdown headers. I am using the regex `(\#)(.*?)\1` which does a great job to match the following:

```
#Markdown Title#
```

However, it also matches the following, which I don't want:

```
#Markdown Title #
```

**How can I modify my regex so that the beginning # cannot have a space after, and the closing # cannot have a space before?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need lookaheads at all. You can just use this, which checks for non-whitespace characters (`\S`) adjacent to the `#` markers, and also checks for the case where the title is only one character long:

```
\#(\S.*\S|\S)\#
```

You could make this slightly shorter by using `\#(\S(.*\S)?)\#`, but it will make processing your capturing group a little trickier if you need it.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RfcA1o/3

Comment: Note that this will only work if there are at least two characters between the opening and closing "#". In other words, it will match neither "#a#", nor "##".

Comment: Thank you, updated. I'm not sure if OP wants to match "##"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression), Lookarounds are supported. So, you may use a negative Lookahead to make sure there's no space after the first "#" and a negative Lookbehind to make sure there's no space before the last one.

Try with the following pattern:

```
(\#)(?!\s)([^#]*)(?<!\s)\1
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/22vQYY/1)**.

Note that the capturing groups are not necessary here (unless you need them for some other reason). So, you can just use:

```
\#(?!\s)[^#]*(?<!\s)\#
```

Side note: those patterns (along with your original one) will match "##". If that's not what you want, you may use the `+` quantifier instead of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Following jdaz's answer. You don't need to use look-aheads but this will capture just the contents regardless of the amount of spacing on either side. Then re-add your hashes if needed.

```
\#\s*(.*?)\s*\#
```